# MikroTik EAP-TLS WiFi Config using Certificates

Tags: ssl, wifi, mikrotik, access-point, eap

What are the ***upsides*** and ***downsides*** of using EAP-TLS authentication with certificates for WiFi client connections? How is this superior than just using standard WPA2 password authentication?

How do I configure EAP-TLS authentication for an **MikroTik** router?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Using EAP-TLS certificates to authenticate WiFi clients:

### Upsides:

- **Granular Access Control**: Access can be both granted and restricted on a *certificate* basis, unlike WPA2 authentication where all users share the same password for the SSID
- **Identity Validation**: WPA2 password auth only proves a connecting WiFi user knows a password. A Certificate validates the identity of both users and the AP they're connecting to
- **Traffic Encrypted between Client & Router**: The "***TLS***" part of "EAP-**TLS**" ensures traffic between client & router is encrypted. Which is quite nice...

### Downsides:

- **Higher Administrative Burden**: Creating certificates for each WiFi user and configuring their access requires more effort than setting a shared password.
- **Unsuitable for Public Networks**: Hotels, airports, cafes, etc cannot configure certificate based access for their large, transient WiFi user populations.

### HowTo COMPATIBILITY:

- ***RouterOS Versions***: Procedures were documented and developed using ***RouterOS v6.45.1 through v 6.46 ***. Tested & known to work correctly as of 20191214.
- ***Certificate Creation Procedures***: Tested and known to work with IOS 11-13.3 and OSX Mojave and Catalina clients.  YMMV if connecting Windows or other clients using EAP-TLS.

### WARNING:

The ***RouterOS*** CLI commands offered in this tutorial make excellent templates. But you **MUST** review and change my place holders and default values ***including the certificate export passphrase*** before executing commands in this tutorial.

### CONFIGURATION PROCESS OVERVIEW: MikroTik ROUTER

A) **CREATE CERTIFICATES**: (3) types of certs must be created:

- **Server**: Create a Certificate for MikroTik side of EAP-TLS connection. This will be used by the wireless interface using EAP-TLS authentication.
- **Client(s)**: Create a certificate for **EACH** Client connecting to the SSID using the wireless interface we configure for EAP-TLS.
- **Certificate Authority**: This certificate used to create a ***Chain of Trust*** for certs by signing both Client & Server certs.

B) **CONFIGURE Wireless Security Profiles**: Specify the certificates in Wireless *Security Profiles*. We will create a wireless `Security Profile` for the wireless interface using EAP-TLS authentication and for each connecting client.

C) **CONFIGURE Wireless Interface**: Finally, we will create a wireless interface specifying the wireless `Security Profile` for the interface.

### SECTION 1: CREATE CERTIFICATES

### Create **CA** (Certificate Authority) Certificate:

```
/certificate add name=CAF1Linux-template common-name=CAF1Linux country=GB days-valid=3650 key-size=4096 locality="Your Town" organization="Your Orgsanization" state=YourCounty trusted=yes unit="Technical Services" subject-alt-name="IP:1.2.3.4" key-usage=digital-signature,key-cert-sign,crl-sign;

/certificate sign CAF1Linux-template ca-crl-host="1.2.3.4" name=CAF1Linux
```

Export a ***PEM*** Format Cert:

```
/certificate export-certificate CAF1Linux export-passphrase="REPLACE ME WITH YOUR OWN CERTIFICATE PASSPHRASE"
```

The command `/certificate export-certificate` creates (2) new certs in files:

```
 cert_export_CAF1Linux.crt
 cert_export_CAF1Linux.key
```

Export a ***PKCS12*** Format Cert:

```
/certificate export-certificate CAF1Linux export-passphrase="REPLACE ME WITH YOUR OWN CERTIFICATE PASSPHRASE" type=pkcs12
```

Appending `type=pkcs12` to the `/certificate export-certificate` command will produce the following in Files":

```
cert_export_CAF1Linux.p12
```

### Create **SERVER** Certificate:

This is the certificate used by the MikroTik's wireless interface offering EAP-TLS authentication.

**NOTE**: You'll remark in `key-usage` I additionally specify `ipsec-tunnel,ipsec-end-system`. I use the same certs for both WiFi and VPN access, making it easy to centrally revoke a cert for both services if a server is compromised or to revoke a user's access.

```
/certificate add name=F1LinuxServer-template common-name="F1LinuxServer" country=GB days-valid=3650 key-size=4096 locality="Your City or Town" organization="Your Company" state=YourStateOrCounty trusted=yes unit="Technical Services" subject-alt-name="IP:1.2.3.4" key-usage=digital-signature,data-encipherment,key-agreement,ipsec-tunnel,ipsec-end-system,tls-server,tls-client;

/certificate sign F1LinuxServer-template ca=CAF1Linux name=F1LinuxServer

/certificate set F1LinuxServer trusted=yes
```

Export a ***PEM*** Format Cert:

```
/certificate export-certificate F1LinuxServer export-passphrase="REPLACE ME WITH YOUR OWN CERTIFICATE PASSPHRASE"
```

Export a ***PKCS12*** Format Cert: Apple Clients require pkcs12 certs, so we will export all Client certs additionally in pkcs12 format

```
/certificate export-certificate F1LinuxServer export-passphrase="REPLACE ME WITH YOUR OWN CERTIFICATE PASSPHRASE" type=pkcs12
```

Repeat above process to create a unique certificate for **EACH** connecting client.

### Create **CLIENT** Certificates:

An example for a MacBook is shown below, however the process is the same for any device supporting EAP-TLS auth.

```
/certificate add name=F1LinuxClientMacBook-template common-name=F1LinuxClientIpadPro country=GB days-valid=3650 key-size=4096 locality="Your City or Town" organization="Your Company" state=YourStateOrCounty trusted=yes unit="Technical Services" subject-alt-name="" key-usage=digital-signature,data-encipherment,key-agreement,ipsec-tunnel,ipsec-end-system,tls-client;

/certificate sign F1LinuxClientMacbook-template ca=CAF1Linux name=F1LinuxClientMacBook

/certificate set F1LinuxClientMacBook trusted=yes
```

Export a ***PEM*** Format Cert:

```
/certificate export-certificate F1LinuxClientMacBook export-passphrase="REPLACE ME WITH A DIFFERENT PASSPHRASE FOR EACH CLIENT CERTIFICATE"
```

Export a ***PKCS12*** Format Cert:

```
/certificate export-certificate F1LinuxClientMacBook export-passphrase="REPLACE ME WITH A DIFFERENT PASSPHRASE FOR EACH CLIENT CERTIFICATE" type=pkcs12
```

### SECTION 2: CONFIGURE WIRELESS SECURITY PROFILES

After creating certificates for each connecting wireless client using EAP-TLS authentication, you can use these certificates to create Wireless *Security Profile*'s.

Unlike standard WPA2 password encryption which sets a single password for all connecting clients, since each wireless client will have a unique certificate, we must create a *Security Profile* for each device and the wireless interface itself.

### SERVER `Security Profile`

```
/interface wireless security-profiles add name="24083_F1_EAP_TLS_Server" mode=dynamic-keys authentication-types=wpa2-eap unicast-ciphers=aes-ccm group-ciphers=aes-ccm wpa-pre-shared-key="" wpa2-pre-shared-key="" supplicant-identity="" eap-methods=eap-tls tls-mode=verify-certificate tls-certificate=F1LinuxServer mschapv2-username="" mschapv2-password="" disable-pmkid=no static-algo-0=none static-key-0="" static-algo-1=none static-key-1="" static-algo-2=none static-key-2="" static-algo-3=none static-key-3="" static-transmit-key=key-0 static-sta-private-algo=none static-sta-private-key="" radius-mac-authentication=yes radius-mac-accounting=yes radius-eap-accounting=yes interim-update=0s radius-mac-format=XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX radius-mac-mode=as-username radius-called-format=mac:ssid radius-mac-caching=disabled group-key-update=5m management-protection=allowed management-protection-key=""
```

### CLIENT `Security Profile`

```
/interface wireless security-profiles add name="24083_F1_EAP_TLS_MacBook" mode=dynamic-keys authentication-types=wpa2-eap unicast-ciphers=aes-ccm group-ciphers=aes-ccm wpa-pre-shared-key="" wpa2-pre-shared-key="" supplicant-identity="" eap-methods=eap-tls tls-mode=verify-certificate tls-certificate=F1LinuxClientMacBook mschapv2-username="" mschapv2-password="" disable-pmkid=no static-algo-0=none static-key-0="" static-algo-1=none static-key-1="" static-algo-2=none static-key-2="" static-algo-3=none static-key-3="" static-transmit-key=key-0 static-sta-private-algo=none static-sta-private-key="" radius-mac-authentication=yes radius-mac-accounting=yes radius-eap-accounting=yes interim-update=0s radius-mac-format=XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX radius-mac-mode=as-username radius-called-format=mac:ssid radius-mac-caching=disabled group-key-update=5m management-protection=allowed management-protection-key=""
```

***Repeat the above command for each device authenticating with EAP-TLS, remembering to change the name of the certificate.***

### SECTION 3: CONFIGURE VIRTUAL AP WITH EAP AUTH

Finally configure a wireless interface to use the server's EAP-TLS Security Profile:

```
/interface wireless name="wlan1010" mtu=1500 l2mtu=1600 mac-address=74:4D:28:XX:XX:XX arp=proxy-arp interface-type=virtual master-interface=wlan5ghz mode=ap-bridge ssid="240E83_F1_EAP" vlan-mode=no-tag vlan-id=1 wds-mode=disabled wds-default-bridge=none wds-ignore-ssid=no bridge-mode=enabled default-authentication=no default-forwarding=yes default-ap-tx-limit=0 default-client-tx-limit=0 hide-ssid=yes security-profile=24083_F1_EAP_TLS_Server
```

### BACKUP CONFIG AND CERTIFICATES:

Now that you've gone to all this effort, ensure you backup the config.  I use the naming convvention for my backups ***RBmodelNumber-YearMonthDay-Time_ROSversionNumber.rsc***:

```
/export compact file=RB4011-20191214-1644_ROSv6.46.0.rsc
```

**PLEASE NOTE***: Although you can restore the ***configuration*** to a new MikroTik, those backups ***won't*** capture your certificates.  Open a web browser and connect to the MikroTik via a WebGUI. Go to the "***Files***" menu and you can download each of them to your laptop and then punt them somewhere secure & sensible for long-term storage.

### CLIENT CONFIGURATION

To learn how to configure IOS & OSX Clients to use EAP-TLS authentication, go [HERE](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/326208/how-do-i-configure-an-ipad-to-use-eap-tls)

Comment: Hello @F1Linux, thank you for the detailed guide! I have a question regarding CA and VPN. In my case I want to use Windows CA to make certificate deployment automated and as Windows CA is used as only CA in our office. The issue is that Im confused about the certificates themselves. What kind of certificate from Mikrotik should I request from Windows CA to get EAP working for either VPN and WiFi, what is the correct key usage?